# What is the algorithm browsers use to handle z-index?

Tags: css

**Could someone provide the algorithm/pseudocode that browsers use to handle z-index?** I always seem to run into corner cases where my expectation does not meet observed behavior when using z-index. I think perhaps the best way to understand the z-index is by studying the algorithm browsers use to handle it. I thought the algorithm would be something like:

```
render(Node n)
{
    var contexts = [n.stackingContext]; // initialize by creating a single root context
    for(var child in n.children)
    {
        if (child has a z-index set using either z-index:number or z-index:inherit)
        {
            create new stacking context with z-index = z-index above and
            insert this stackingContext into appropriate position in contexts such that
            contexts is always sorted in increasing order of z-index
        }
    }
    for(var context in contexts)
    {
        for(var node in context.nodes) // context.nodes returns nodes in increasing order of z-index
        {
            render(node);
        }
    }
}
```

and the method would be called like `render(document.body)` to render entire DOM, but above pseudocode does not give expected result when i run it on example below:

E.g., W.r.t. this code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div0">
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
}

#div0
{
z-index:69;    
}

#div1
{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,255,0.8);
}

#div2
{
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:10;
    background:rgba(0,255,0,0.8);
}

#div3
{
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:5;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}
```

js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z7hemun3/9/

I expect div3 to be at the top since it will create a new stacking context whereas div1 will share stacking context of its parent and stacking context of a child (div3 in this case) appears on top of stacking context of a parent (div0 is parent of div3). However, div2 appears at the top followed by div3 then div1. **So looks like stacking contexts of div2 and div3 compete with each other even though div2 and div3 are at different levels in the dom tree.**

For a moment, above seemed to violate what I learnt from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7hemun3/5/

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>


div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
}

#div1
{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:10;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}

#div2
{
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:1;
    background:rgba(0,255,0,0.8);
}

#div3
{
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    background:rgba(0,0,255,0.8);
}
```

Lesson I got from second fiddle is that child element will always be displayed on top of parent even if its z-index is less than that of parent.

Comment: here is a few articles/posts you should read about z-index: [CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) | [understanding z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index) | [Adding Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index)

Answer (score 3):

I am not going to address the specific algorithm so much as the way that these indexes are calculated.

In your first example, the three (red, green, and blue) divs (1-3) are *nested* (children) elements to the (parent) div0 element.

> Z-Indexing is *relative* with regards to the closest **positioned** *parent* element.

Since you used the css directive applying `position:absolute` to every div, every div element became "positioned".

Once the nesting was taken in to account, div0 is at 69. However, with regards to its *children* that div is at z-index 0 because it is now the relatively positioned element. The children's z-index of default(0),5, and 10 all stack on top of the parent div0. Relative to div0, they are 0, 5, and 10 above it. Relative to the parent of div0 they are 69, 74, and 79 above it.